# 95 Aerostar Dash lights

Tags: electrical, ford, ac

thank you all for your efforts to help each other.
My '95  Aerostar's dash lights, A/C and radio turn off when I brake. Anyone have an idea what the issue is?

Comment: Check the earth or ground connection on the rear lights.

Comment: O/PI cleaned the terminals and the ground too. No change.

Comment: Then check the ground points for the dash - there are usually several: clean and tight...